# Collecting a raw stream into a typed collection?

Tags: java, java-stream, type-parameter, generic-collections, raw-types

I am calling a library method that returns a raw `Stream`. I know the type of the elements in the stream and want to collect into a collection with the declared element type. What is the nice, or the not so appalling way of doing it?

### Minimal reproducible example

For the sake of a reproducible example suppose I want to call this method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
static Stream getStream() {
    return Stream.of("Example");
}
```

I had hoped that this would work, and I have not understood why it doesn’t:

```
    List<String> stringList = getStream().map(s -> (String) s).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I get *Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to List*. Why?

### Workaround

An unchecked cast works. To narrow down the bit that needs to be marked as deliberately unchecked, we may do

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Stream<String> stringStream = getStream();
    List<String> stringList = stringStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

On both Java 8 and Java 11 the returned list is a `java.util.ArrayList`, and it contains the expected `String` element.

### What my search turned up or not

I tried my search engine searching for terms like *java collect raw stream*. It didn’t lead me to anything helpful. There’s a closed Java bug (link at the bottom) mentioning that once you operate on raw types, everything gets raw. But this fully raw version doesn’t work either:

```
    List stringList = getStream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am still getting *Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to List*. How come?

We are coding for Java 8 (a little while still).

I know this question has something opinion-based about it. I am still hoping that you can provide me with some facts that will help me write code that will generally be considered nicer.

### Background: Hibernate 5

The method I want to call is `org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultStream()` on a raw `Query` (a `Query` lacking type parameter). I want to get the stream because I have special requirements for the type of collection I am collecting into. In my production code I am using `Collectors.toCollection()` (not `Collectors.toLlist()` as in the example in this question). BTW while writing this question I found a way to persuade Hibernate to return a typed stream. I still found the question interesting enough to post.

### Link

- [Problem with casting inside lambdas for java.util.stream.Stream.map method](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223548) in the Java bug database

Comment: A raw type erases all generics used in that type. This is by design. I don't think there's any way around the unchecked cast.

Comment: I might be missing something, but why can't you just cast the stream itself if you know what type of thing it has? `((Stream<String>)getStream())`

Comment: @Sweeper Isn’t that what I am implicitly doing in my workaround? It still looks like a workaround to me. Am I too picky?

Comment: Ah yes, but is there actually an unchecked warning? My IDE didn't issue one... (maybe I configured it not to?)

Comment: @Sweeper My work Eclipse and home Eclipse did differently on that point, so yes, probably a preferences question.

Comment: @Sweeper Compiling directly with `javac` outputs `Note: Main.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.` for me.

Comment: Cast `Stream` to `Stream<?>`. That's the only way to get rid of the raw type without an *unchecked* operation. After that, `map` can be used as intended.

Comment: Hey, @Holger, that sounds indeed like the way I want to go. Feel free to post as an answer if you have got the time. Thanks very much.

Comment: This question has expected behaviour, a specific problem (pasted error message), minimal reproducible example, search and research (workaround found). Just so that I may continue improving (my question track record does not look that good): What does it take for a question not to be downvoted? (I skimmed [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228358/why-are-my-questions-on-stack-overflow-getting-downvotes-without-explanation) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question) without getting closer to an understanding.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hint is in the Java Bug record alright: Once I use a raw type, everything gets raw. `Stream.collect()` is a generic method too, so its raw version returns — `Object`, don’t be surprised.

The `Stream` method I am calling is declared like this:

```
    <R,A> R collect​(Collector<? super T,A,R> collector)
```

So it returns an `R`, and what `R` is it can gather from the passed collector (be it `Collectors.toList()` or some `Collectors.toCollection()`). Once everything has gone raw, the deduction no longer works. And `collect()` returns `Object`.

To conclude: Generics are good. When I cannot avoid getting something raw, convert it to its generic counterpart as early as possible.

**EDIT:** With thanks to Sweeper and Holger for valuable input in comments, this is my preferred solution:

```
    Stream<?> wildcardStream = getStream();
    List<String> stringList = wildcardStream.map(s -> (String) s)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(stringList.getClass());
    System.out.println(stringList);
```

Output on Java 11:

> ```
> class java.util.ArrayList
> [Example]
> ```

Casting `Stream` to `Stream<?>` (either implicitly or explicitly) gets rid of the raw type without an unchecked operation. After that `map()` can be used as intended. And there is no need for `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

This also means that a solution for my original Hibernate scenario is to cast *the `Query` object* to a `Query<?>` before calling `getResultStream()` rather than only casting the stream. And then cast each individual object *in a `map()` in the stream operation* in the same way as above.